# Why does Chrome use sec-ch-ua: "\"Not\\A;Brand";v="99"?

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent, privacy, client-hints

I understand that making [user-agent hints](https://github.com/WICG/ua-client-hints) more ambiguous is intended, in part, to make [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) harder.

My own (Windows desktop) Chrome sends the headers:

```
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="86", "\"Not\\A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="86"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
```

What I don't get is:

1. Why the string "Not A Brand" specifically? Does anyone else use this pseudo-UA? Is this a joke of some sort?
2. Why the `\"` and `\\A;` inside the string? My only guess is that this is supposed to mess with parsers somehow (like the anti-IE hacks in CSS), but that seems like a rather odd purpose — and IIRC, `\A` is the bell character.
3. How is this supposed to accomplish user-agent hint ambiguity, given that it *also* sends the full `user-agent` header, which has the specific version numbers?
4. While at it: why does Chrome's user-agent also claim to be Mozilla, AppleWebKit, and Safari? It isn't, and this `user-agent` string is distinctively Chrome's. Does it have some sort of embedded components from those other browsers?

Comment: To comment on point 2 of you question: I suspect that `\"` gets unescaped to `"` and `\\ ` to `\ `, so the bell character `\A` is never being parsed.

Comment: About point 3 see https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/-2JIRNMWJ7s/m/yHe4tQNLCgAJ it is in the plan to freeze and cleanup the user-agent

Comment: About point 4 see https://web.dev/user-agent-client-hints/#background every new browser had to copy an existing user agent for compatibility reasons and then added new information about itself and its version etc.

Comment: Further on question 4, [every browser pretends to be every other browser (or at least they all claim to be Mozilla)](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/).

Comment: I'm going start my own brand called "Not a brand" right now!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It seems that it's part of Chromium's [GREASEing](https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints/#grease) strategy:

> User agents' brands containing more than a single entry could encourage standardized processing of the UA string. By **randomly including additional, intentionally incorrect**, comma-separated entries with arbitrary ordering, they would **reduce the chance that we ossify** on a few required strings.

---

Looking at the Chromium repository, it seems that it was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/19ad8d3cab21013ce2d40cf2ec84267bb04b08ec)

The commit description given is:

```
[client-hints] GREASEing the Sec-CH-UA list

Randomizing order and string with escaped characters to ensure proper
parsing and prevent ossification.
```

It also links to [this ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1070922) in the bug tracker.

Comment: Having *some* false entry, e.g. "Not A Brand", would fulfill the objectives you bolded. But that doesn't explain why they call it "Not A Brand" specifically — nor why the escaped characters. Well done finding that commit, but its message doesn't really explain those either (nor does the ticket). Hence the specific questions in my OP.

Comment: Going by the commit message I would say the escaped character are there just to ensure that whoever will eventually parse the UA will be forced to correctly implement all the "cases" that could happen in a UA string.

Comment: It's probably a bit off-topic but this feels a lot like what Golang sometimes does, to ensure that people don't rely on "not guaranteed" behaviors. For example: the iteration order on a map is _purposely unpredictable_ just to force programmers to not rely on a specific order. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6719

Comment: Interesting point re using it as a case test. *That* makes sense as a thing one might do; I hadn't thought of what the permitted string content was such that one might want to fuzz it. That seems like a pretty good answer.

Comment: Do I get this right, in order for consumers not to use strict enums for Chromium versions, which might change spontaneously, they randomize the naming strategy with random fillers? If every new release comes with a new pattern, doesn't this make fingerprinting and tracking easier?